# Convert string to list of custom objects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, type-conversion

Say I have an object Fish with properties like

```
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Type As Integer
Public Property Age As Integer
```

And I have a string that looks like this:

```
"Fishes[0].ID=1&Fishes[0].Name=Fred&Fishes[0].Type=1&Fishes[0].Age=3&Fishes[1].ID=2&Fishes[1].Name=George&Fishes[1].Type=2&Fishes[1].Age=5&..."
```

Is there any way of converting/casting/whatever my string into a list of Fish objects? I can't seem to find anything to help. I do have some control over the format of the string if that would make things easier.

Many thanks

Comment: make a extension method

Comment: use var ls=new  List<Fish> and then make a extension

Comment: @skhurams .. why dont you make an answer ?

Comment: @skhurams would you be able to elaborate on this please? Give an example maybe?

Comment: can you explain in detail what you want In my understanding you want a string which you want to convert into list of fishes am i right? then i will answer

Comment: Yes, I have this string and I want a list of fishes, that is correct.

Comment: This looks like an HTTP request.  Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @matt-dot-net I am, I did not mention this as at the point I receive the string it is just a string. Are you suggesting I might be able to turn it into a list of Fish some other way? I may be able to play around with other bits of the code if necessary :S

Comment: Structures are value type and classes are reference type you have to use classes here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to parse the input string to look for `Fishes[X].PROPNAME=VALUE` pattern. Loop through all matches found in the string and add into or set the existing object in Dictionary. Use `X` as each object key in the Dictionary.

Create Fish structure:

```
Structure Fish
    Public ID As String
    Public Name As String
    Public Type As Integer
    Public Age As Integer
End Structure
```

Codes to process the input string:

```
Dim Fishes As New Dictionary(Of String, Fish)
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(str, "Fishes\[(?<key>\d+)]\.(?<prop>.+?)=(?<value>[^&]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Do While m.Success
    Dim key As String = m.Groups("key").Value.Trim.ToUpper
    Dim prop As String = m.Groups("prop").Value.Trim.ToUpper
    Dim value As String = m.Groups("value").Value

    ' if the key not yet exist in the Dictionary, create and add into it.
    If Not Fishes.ContainsKey(key) Then
        Fishes.Add(key, New Fish)
    End If

    Dim thisFish As Fish = Fishes(key) ' get the Fish object for this key

    ' determine the object property to set
    Select Case prop
        Case "ID" : thisFish.ID = value
        Case "NAME" : thisFish.Name = value
        Case "TYPE" : thisFish.Type = CInt(value)
        Case "AGE" : thisFish.Age = CInt(value)
    End Select

    Fishes(key) = thisFish ' since the Fish object is declared as Structure,
                           ' update the Dictionary item of key with the modified object.
                           ' If Fish is declared as Class, then this line is useless

    m = m.NextMatch()
Loop
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for! Thanks very much! I'm not sure there isn't a better way to do this, getting the ModelBinder to help or something, but in the meantime this works (even if it's maybe not ideal). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Structure Test
    Dim ID As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Type As Integer
    Dim Age As Integer
End Structure
```

In your Button click event ..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Fishes As New List(Of Test)

    Dim Fish As New Test
    Fish.ID = "GF"
    Fish.Name = "Gold Fish"
    Fish.Age = 1
    Fish.Type = 1
    Fishes.Add(Fish)

    MsgBox(Fishes(0).Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm quite new to this and I'm not really sure I follow what you're suggesting. My problem exists in the middle of some code, there is no button - a method is passed a string (see the question) and then I need to construct a list of Fish for use in the method. How would I use your answer for this? Thanks

Comment: @Valuk .. are you using winform or what ?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC and VB, but at the point I have the problem, it's just a case of trying to convert a string to a list of objects, isn't it just VB that's relevant? Apologies for any confusion, I'm quite confused myself.

Comment: @Valuk .. If I saw your track .. seems that you wouldnt need this because this codes is winforms purposes .. but you can get an idea by this .. don't get headache .. :P ..

Answer (score 0):

this is vb.net converted

```
Public Partial Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


        If Not IsPostBack Then
        End If

    End Sub
    Public Sub MYtest()
        Dim ls As New List(Of Fish)()
        Dim f As New Fish()
        f.ID = 1
        f.Name = "My name"
        f.Type = "My type"
        f.Age = 20
        ls.Add(f)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Fish
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set
            m_ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Type() As String
        Get
            Return m_Type
        End Get
        Set
            m_Type = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Type As String
    Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Age
        End Get
        Set
            m_Age = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Age As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand, how would I use this to convert my string into a list of Fish?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned that this is via ASP.Net MVC.  The ModelBinder will do everything for you.

```
public ActionResult UpdateFish(IList<Fish> listOfFish)
    {
        //the ModelBinder will figure out that the user has posted a list of Fish instances.
        //do something with listOfFish
        return View(listOfFish);
    }
```

Comment: Apparently (this was done by someone else) the string I'm working with was constructed from the model on the view (in javascript) and then passed into an iframe as a string, and then posted from there. Is there a way of tricking the ModelBinder this has come from a model? Maybe I should reconstruct the model in the iframe before posting _that_ back?

Comment: You don't have to do any tricking.  The ModelBinder will figure out that the user has posted a list of Fish and the action method will be called.